# Updating two columns given condition in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column name 'balance' & 'status'. I got the Qty from users input.
What I want to perform is update balance (balance-qty)
and after updating balance if balance is 0 then I want to change status to 2.
Is it possible to perform these 2 operations in one query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that it one query, all need need to do is to use `InLine IF` statement.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET balance = balance - qty,
    status = IF(balance - qty = 0, 2, status)
// WHERE condition here (if any)...
```

and since you have mentioned that the `Qty` came from the user, please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from `SQL Injection`. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks, it works with little change. I modified if statement status=IF(balance=0,2,status). I guess balance=balance-qty perform first and if statement.

Comment: user input is forced to be numeric, so no need to worry about SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can write something like:

```
UPDATE ...
   SET balance = ...,
       status = CASE WHEN ... = 0 THEN 2 ELSE status END
 WHERE ...
;
```